# Monoidal structure on simplical model category of chain complexes

Tags: simplicial-stuff, model-categories, chain-complexes

For

- $k$ a field (the case I am interested in, but the question makes sense over any dga),
- $\mathrm{Ch}_\bullet(k)$ its projective model category of unbounded chain complexes ([here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model%20structure%20on%20chain%20complexes#StandardModelStructureOnUnboundedComplexes)),
- $\mathrm{sCh}_\bullet(k)$ the Quillen-equivalent simplicial model structure on simplicial objects in $\mathrm{Ch}_\bullet(k)$ ([here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+chain+complexes#LocalizedReedyModelStructureOnSimplicialUnboundedChainComplexes)),

  i.e the Reedy model structure Bousfield-localized at totalization-equivalences

there probably is a *monoidal* enhancement of $\mathrm{sCh(k)}$ which makes the Quillen equivalence

$$
  \mathrm{const}  
  \,\colon\,
  \mathrm{Ch}_\bullet(k)
  \rightleftarrows
  \mathrm{sCh}_\bullet(k)
  \,\colon\,
  \mathrm{ev}_0
$$

be *monoidal* with respect to the standard monoidal structure on $\mathrm{Ch}_\bullet(k)$?

And probably that's the Day convolution structure on $\mathrm{sCh}_\bullet(k)$?

Did anyone work this out? It seems a tedious check, but maybe there is some shortcut.

Comment: I'm not too well-versed on monoidal model categories, but the natural candidate seems like the pointwise monoidal structure on $sCh(k)$. It certainly makes the $const\dashv ev_0$ adjunction monoidal, so the question is only whether it makes $sCh(k)$ a monoidal model structure. This I don't know.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi My reasoning: The Bousfield localization of $\mathrm{sCh}_\bullet(k)$ which makes it equivalent to $\mathrm{Ch}_\bullet(k)$ inverts the "realization"-equivalences, hence those maps that are quasi-isos on totalized chain complexes. But in forming the total chain complex of a simplicial object in chain complexes, the simplicial degrees get mixed with the chain degrees. Therefore I expect that any compatible monoidal structure needs to be additive between simplicial and chain degrees, too. This is not the case for the objectwise tensor, but is the case for the Day convolution tensor.

Comment: At least at the level of $\infty$-categories, the realization functor is canonically symmetric monoidal (as a functor $Fun(\Delta^{op},D(k))\to D(k)$), where the source has the pointwise tensor product (because $\Delta^{op}$ is sifted). Again, I'm unsure how this works for model categories, so maybe this fact is misleading

Comment: In this case, $\Delta^{op}$ isn't monoidal by itself - it's only promonoidal, and in a way such that the associated Day convolution monoidal structure is the pointwise tensor product. --- When asking for a monoidal enhancement of $sCh(k)$, are you asking for it to be compatible with the simplicial part of a simplicial model structure?

Comment: @TylerLawson thanks. Oh I see, hm. But yes, I was hoping for a simplicial monoidal structure. Basically I'd like to do what one usually does with the model structure on chain complexes, but now instead with its simplicial enhancement. But maybe I am being too naive about it.

Comment: @UrsSchreiber I suspect that the easiest way through this would be to say that $sCh(k)$ is a symmetric monoidal closed model category (under the pointwise tensor), and that the map $sSet \to sCh(k)$, given by taking free $k$-modules levelwise, is strong monoidal left Quillen. That automatically would lift the self-enriched model structure to a simplicial model structure.

Comment: @TylerLawson all right, thanks, so let's look at the pointwise tensor structure. I still wonder: (1) Does this monoidal structure pass to a monoidal model category structure on the Bousfield localization of $\mathrm{sCh}_\bullet(k)$ at the realization equivalences and (2) does it make the Quillen equivalence $\mathrm{Ch}(k) \simeq_{\mathrm{Qu}} \mathrm{sCh}(k)$ a monoidal Quillen adjunction?

Comment: @UrsSchreiber: (1) is easy to see using Barwick's criterion for monoidality of left Bousfield localizations: tensoring a local equivalence in sCh(k) with an object in Ch(k) again gives a local equivalence because tensoring commutes with homotopy colimits.  (2) follows since the derived unit and counit are weak equivalences, which itself follows from the fact that local objects in sCh(k) are homotopy constant diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

This first part of [my PhD thesis](https://wesscholar.wesleyan.edu/etd_diss/39/) considered the question: "If $M$ is a monoidal model category, and $C$ is a set of morphisms such that the left Bousfield localization $L_C(M)$ exists, when is the model structure $L_C(M)$ monoidal?" To guarantee the existence, one can assume $M$ is left proper and either cellular or combinatorial, but those hypotheses are not needed to answer the question.

The answer is: "$L_C(M)$ is monoidal if and only if the class of morphisms $f\otimes K$, where $f$ is a morphism in $C$ and $K$ is a cofibrant object, is contained in the $C$-local equivalences." Often, it suffices to check this for $K$ one of the domains or codomains of the generating cofibrations. This is Theorem 4.5 and 4.6 of my paper [Monoidal Bousfield Localization and Algebras Over Operads](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5197) published in Equivariant Topology and Derived Algebra, Cambridge University Press, pp. 179-239, 2021. It assumes that $M$ is cofibrantly generated and that cofibrant objects are flat, i.e., $g\otimes K$ is a weak equivalence if $g$ is and if $K$ is cofibrant.

Dmitri Pavlov's comment explains that, in your situation, the condition of this theorem is satisfied, so $L_C(M) = \mathrm{sCh}_\bullet(k)$ is a monoidal model category. The paper of Barwick that Dmitri mentions is "[On left and right model categories and left and right Bousfield localizations](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/homology-homotopy-and-applications/volume-12/issue-2/On-left-and-right-model-categories-and-left-and-right/hha/1296223884.full)." There, Theorem 4.46 gives conditions under which enriched localization exists (with a different proof than mine, different hypotheses, and not a characterization), and monoidal localization is of course a special case. In your case, Barwick's conditions are also satisfied so you can use either result.

As for making the Quillen adjunction $
  \mathrm{const}  
  \,\colon\,
  \mathrm{Ch}_\bullet(k)
  \rightleftarrows
  \mathrm{sCh}_\bullet(k)
  \,\colon\,
  \mathrm{ev}_0
$ monoidal, I don't think this question was considered by either Barwick or my paper. You just have to check it directly, but Dmitri's comment shows you how. A reference for what must be checked is Definition 4.2.16 in Hovey's book. For you, the unit is cofibrant, so you only need to know that your adjunction is already Quillen (ignoring monoidal structures), and that the left adjoint is a monoidal functor. But this is clear, because you use the pointwise monoidal structure.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks again to @DmitriPavlov. I'll turn that into a note on the nLab. For starters I have finally recorded your thesis here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bousfield+localization+of+model+categories#White14